# Error processing lifecycle processing instructions with pom.xml in demo Maven project in STS

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml, spring-tool-suite

I am having difficulty going through a guide for creating a RESTful web service using Spring. This is because things will not run, ostensibly because there is a problem with the pom.xml file. The error it's reporting is "Error processing lifecycle processing." When I try to do things with Maven in the command line in this project, I get the error non-parseable pom. I'm working in STS on a very simple project just to get things set up. None of the similar questions on here had solutions that worked for me. I'm including my pom.xml file here in case there's anything obviously wrong with it:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question as I figured it out: The problem was owing to the version of the parent. 2.0.2.RELEASE led to this error. Using 2.0.1.RELEASE instead fixed the problem.